# rotation change not triggered anymore

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I have an app with a viewcontroller.
I have overwriting following methods:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(
        toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation,
        duration: NSTimeInterval) {

override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
```

`override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool` is not implemented.

I am rotating my device from portrait to landscape, but no of the methods are triggered. I know that my viewWillTransitionToSize is triggered yesterday, but now it doesn't. I can't see what could be the reason.

I don't see any change from my side regarding the rotation detection.

Does someone has a hint ?

**UPDATE**

Sorry volks. It was a stupid failure by me.
I had a parent uiviewcontroller with viewWillTransitionToSize implemented and forgot to call the super, so it will also recognize the rotation in my subview.

Oh I am so sorry for all wasting the time with this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: just add this , see if it works:- [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];

Comment: I dont see (Syntax error) an method attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation in my viewcontroller. I tried to add self.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation() in my viewdidappear, is this correct ?

Comment: yes... that is right...now check!

Comment: I get an syntax error in my XCode  "Static member 'attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation' cannot be used on instance of type 'MyViewController'

Comment: that's wrong, it should be  UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()

Comment: got it. I tried, but no of the methods are called. Any hints ?

Comment: I found the problem, Sorry for wasting your time with this. I updated the question

Comment: Please don't change the question to mark it solved. If an answer solved it, mark the answer as accepted; or you can also write your own answer. If the question is no longer relevant *including for any future reader* and has no upvoted answers, then you can also delete it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I will do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You can use**

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window in Appdelegate

Comment: I would like to call my mentoined methods as it already worked fine . Any hint ?

Comment: I found the problem, Sorry for wasting your time with this. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Sorry volks. It was a stupid failure by me. I had a parent uiviewcontroller with `viewWillTransitionToSize` implemented and forgot to call the super, so it will also recognize the rotation in my subview.